# Remover objeto do array atual no foreach?

Tags: javascript

Preciso retirar do `array` o objeto atual sendo processado:

```
arrai = [{parent:1,dialog_node:2}, {parent:1,dialog_node:3}, {parent:1,dialog_node:4}, {parent:9,dialog_node:1}, {parent:9,dialog_node:6}];
tree = {parent:1,dialog_node:2};
arrai.forEach(function(value){
              if(tree.parent == value.parent){
                  node.parent = value.parent;
                  node.children.push(value.dialog_node);
                  _.reject(arrai, function(el) { 
                         return el.dialog_node === tree.dialog_node; });
                    }
              });
```

Gostaria que ao final os elementos que se encaixarem no `if` estejam fora do `array`.

Comment: se tem o exemplo desse array?

Comment: remover um item do array no qual o `forEach` está sendo executado não é uma boa ideia, melhor adicionar uma referência de tudo que deseja remover num outro array, e após o `forEach` excluir tudo

Comment: Ajustado @VirgilioNovic

Answer (score 2):

Para se remover um item do Array durante a interação, o interessante é que realize a interação iniciando pelo final.:

```js
var lista = [
  { id: 1, text: 'texto 01' },
  { id: 2, text: 'texto 02' },
  { id: 3, text: 'texto 03' },
  { id: 4, text: 'texto 04' },
  { id: 5, text: 'texto 05' },
];

lista.reverse()
for (var i = lista.length -1; i >=0; i--) {
  var item = lista[i];
  lista.splice(i, 1);  
  console.log(item)
}

console.log(lista)
```

uma outra possibilidade, é a utilização do `filter`, uma vez que o filter não irá modificar a lista original.

```js
var lista = [
  { id: 1, text: 'texto 01' },
  { id: 2, text: 'texto 02' },
  { id: 3, text: 'texto 03' },
  { id: 4, text: 'texto 04' },
  { id: 5, text: 'texto 05' },
];

lista = lista.filter(function (item, i) {
  console.log(item);
  return false;
})

console.log(lista)
```